# iOS 7 status bar overlapping UI - Need solution for Cordova 3.0

Tags: javascript, cordova, ios7, statusbar

I have a PhoneGap / **Cordova 3.0** app. The status bar overlaps the UI in iOS7. I've read many answers saying to use margin-top:20px or a custom StatusBar plugin. the problem is that with margin-top, when I have a text input in focus, it pushes all the view up (which is expected), and when it loses focus, the view stays at the top and ignores the margin 20px value.

The StatusBar plugin needs Cordova 3.1, and I want to use the 3.0 version, so the plugin solution is not good for my specific application.

Is there a solution to solve the statusbar overlapping issue in Cordova 3.0?

I want the statusbar to be **active** (not hidden). I develop on windows using AppBuilder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you **don't want to hide status bar** [check this solution](http://coenraets.org/blog/2013/09/phonegap-and-cordova-with-ios-7/)

```
function onDeviceReady() {
    if (parseFloat(window.device.version) === 7.0) {
          document.body.style.marginTop = "20px";
    }
}


document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);
```

OR 
**Hide the status bar**

Open Project in xcode first select checkbox ( hide during application launch ) under status bar style - general project settings in xcode 
[image]

select projectname-info.plist (Resources section in xcode)  [image]

and add key "View controller-based status bar appearance" and value "NO" [image]

Comment: Is this code hides the statusbar? - I want it to be active. BTW: I don't have XCode, I develop on Windows using AppBuilder.

Comment: this method will hide the status bar

Comment: My fault for not mentioning it. I want it active. Sorry.

Comment: Thats exactly what I've done. The problem is that when I click an input field and the webview goes up, it doesn't return to the original margin-top:20px when the text input loses focus, it stays at the top most part (0px). That's exactly my issue.

Comment: You need to write an event for when the keyboard shows and hides that will push the UIView up and back down as well and on orientation change.

I tried this and spend countless hours trying to fix the UIView with a phonegap and the status bar issue for iOS 7 the best solution so far is to hide the status bar.

Comment: @StephenCorcoran I know it's the best one, but I want the statusbar to be active :) - There is a plugin for >= Cordova 3.1, but not for 3.0. My problem is that 3.2 has lots of bugs in my app and I was forced to stay with 3.0. I think that I might just use an opaque background color, this will help me out. Don't know how to do this though.

Comment: @IdanShechter I will see if I can dig up my code for that, the only issue was it that the status bar will overlay the phonegap page

Comment: What are the issues if you upgrade to Cordova 3.3?

Comment: @StephenCorcoran http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22670896/phonegap-getpicture-function-long-delay-resumes-on-recall

Answer (score 1):

It's easy. Try use this one.

Put this code inside your MainViewController.m right after MainViewController @implementation and before @end.

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews{

    if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(topLayoutGuide)]) // iOS 7 or above
    {
        CGFloat top = self.topLayoutGuide.length;
        if(self.webView.frame.origin.y == 0){
            // We only want to do this once, or if the view has somehow been "restored" by other code.
            self.webView.frame = CGRectMake(self.webView.frame.origin.x, self.webView.frame.origin.y + top, self.webView.frame.size.width, self.webView.frame.size.height - top);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the lost of focus,

```
var currentIosVersion = getCurrentIosVersion();//RETURNS IOS VERSION OF THE DEVICE

if(currentIosVersion == "7")
{

    /* if there is status bar then replace 768  by 748 
       Presence of status bar in our project can be detected via Cordova plugin
    */

    var content="width=device-width, height=768, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0,target-densityDpi=device-dpi";
    document.getElementsByName('viewport')[0].content = content;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add this line at config.xml

```
 <preference name="fullscreen" value="false" />
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Answer (score 0):

In case that somebody has same problem in Cordova 4, what it worked for me was to install StatusBar plugin:

[image: Plugin Management]

And then add next code to the app (inside of main function):

```
StatusBar.overlaysWebView(false);
```

To personalize color, I added this one also:

```
StatusBar.backgroundColorByHexString("#1b75bc");
```

You can find documentation [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-statusbar#statusbaroverlayswebview)